# Suggestions for codes format to set the chart coordinates,title and added text in excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

Wrote a macro to draw line with markers plot with excel, it works well in a single macro xlsm file. But when I tried to convert it to a excel addin (xlam file) , it got a lot of bugs. All the bugs are related to the format of both X and Y coordinates, position, font type and size of chart title, and position, font type and sizeof added text. Not sure what is the reason, need to know the correct format of them. Any debug suggestions or help, really appreciated. Please see the error message and my full macro codes as the following. Thanks.

The error message is run time error '-21474627161 (800004003)': the object is no longer valid.

[image]
[image]

After you clicked the debug,  the code " .left=358" was highlighted with yellow.

But you checked with excel, the plot was drawn without chart title and the add text (that I want) and the  format of coordinate was not that I tried to set.  Again all these errors only happen with the xlam file, the macro works well with xlms fie.

```
Sub strain_plot()


    sh_rows = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B65535").End(xlUp).Row


    For i = 1 To sh_rows

        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value < 0.000001 Then

            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 1000000000# * ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value

        End If
    Next i


    ii = sh_rows


    c_name = "chart1"

    On Error GoTo err:
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(c_name).Delete
    err:
    Set ch = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(330, 120, 480, 270)  'set graph position and size
    ch.Name = c_name



    With ch.Chart

    For iii = 1 To 2

    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(iii).Values = Range(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, iii + 1), ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ii, iii + 1))
    .SeriesCollection(iii).XValues = Range(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ii, 1))


    .SeriesCollection(iii).ChartType = xlLineMarkers

    Next iii

    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "[110]"
    .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerStyle = 2
    .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerSize = 12
    .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)



    .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "[001]"
    .SeriesCollection(2).MarkerStyle = 2
    .SeriesCollection(2).MarkerSize = 12
    .SeriesCollection(2).MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(96, 96, 96)
    .SeriesCollection(2).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(96, 96, 96)
    .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(96, 96, 96)


       With .Legend

            .IncludeInLayout = False
            .Position = xlLegendPositionRight
            .AutoScaleFont = False
            .Font.Size = 14
            .Top = 25
            .Left = 392
            .Width = 72
            .Height = 40

        End With



    With .ChartArea.Fill

      .Visible = msoTrue
          .ForeColor.SchemeColor = 33

          .Solid

    End With


     With .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)  'red
            .Transparency = 0

    End With



     With .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(96, 96, 96) 'grey
            .Transparency = 0
    End With



    .HasTitle = True
        With .ChartTitle

        .Text = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 8)
         .Left = 358
         .Top = 236

        With .Font

        .Name = "Tahoma"
        .Size = 10


        End With

    End With


      With .Axes(xlCategory)

        .HasTitle = True
        .AxisTitle.Text = "Position(nm)"  'X-axis title
        .TickLabels.Font.Size = 10 'X-axis coordinate number size
        .AxisTitle.Font.Size = 14  'X-axis title word font size
        .TickMarkSpacing = 3
        .TickLabelSpacing = 5
        .TickLabels.NumberFormatLocal = "#,##0._);[red](#,##0.)"
        .TickLabels.NumberFormatLocal = "#,##0_);[red](#,##0)"
        .TickLabels.NumberFormatLocal = "0_);[red](0.)"

    End With

      With .Axes(xlValue)

       .HasTitle = True
       .AxisTitle.Text = "Strain"   'Y-aixs title
       .AxisTitle.Font.Size = 14  'y-axis title word font size
       'Minimum value of Y axis
       .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -0.005
       .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormatLocal = "0.0%"

       End With

    End With


      Dim thechartobj As ChartObject

    Set thechartobj = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(ch.Name)

    Dim thechart As Chart

    Set thechart = thechartobj.Chart

    Dim thetextbox As Shape

    Set thetextbox = thechart.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 688, 372, 122, 20)
    With thetextbox.TextFrame.Characters

    .Text = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 8)

    With .Font

      .Name = "tahoma"
      .Size = 10
      .Bold = msoTrue

      End With

     End With


    End Sub
```

Comment: What is/are the specific error message(s), and on what line(s)?

Comment: run time error '-21474627161 (800004003)': the object is no longer valid.  After you clicked the debug,  the code " .left=358" was highlighted with yellow.  But you checked with excel, the plot was drawn without chart title and the add text (that I want) and the  format of coordinate was not that I tried to set.  Again all these errors only happen with the xlam file, the macro works well with xlms fie. thx .HasTitle = True
    With .ChartTitle
   
    .Text = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 8)
     .Left = 358
     .Top = 236